# Probabilities in probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{P}$) with $\Omega = [-1,1] \times [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given is the probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathcal{P}$) with $\Omega = [-1,1] \times [-1,1] \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{B_\mathbb{R}^2 }\cap \Omega$ and $P(A) = |A| /c$ for a constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

A denotes the area of A, for example $|[0, 0.5] \times [0.2, 0.7]| = (0.5 - 0) (0.7 - 0.2) = 0.25$

How can one calculate the following probabilities?

$a) A = \{(x,y) \in \Omega, x > y \}$

$b) B = \{(x,y) \in \Omega, x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$

$c) C = \{(x,y) \in \Omega, x = 0\}$

$d) D = A \cap B$

I would have taken the events $A = [0, 1]\times [0, 1]$ and $B = [-1, 0]\times[-1, 0]$. Then  $A\cap B = \{(0, 0)\}$, but I'm not quite sure how one has to calculate the probabilites here. And I also think that $c = |\Omega|$ in order for $P$ to be a probability measure.

How should one go about this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you find $|A|, |B|$ etc from what you learned in high-school geometry (or even middle-school math) instead of relying on high=flown language about Borel sets and the like?

Comment: @DilipSarwate You mean like $P\{(x,y):x^2 + y^2 < 1\} = \pi/4$?

Comment: Yes!! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Sorry, but I don't know how to do it for the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the constant, you are correct that $c$ should be the area of the square for it to be a probability measure. In this case, $c = 4$.

All the sets that you are required to take probabilities of are Borel sets. While the measure-theoretic language is fine, in the end the probability measure you are dealing with is just area as we traditionally know it, scaled down by the appropriate constant $c$. The probabilities are as follows:

(a) A represents the right triangle with vertices $(-1,-1)$, $(1,1)$, and $(1,-1)$. (Technically the triangle should be drawn with a dashed line along the diagonal but solid lines on the base and height up to the vertices.) It's area is $1/2*b*h = 1/2*2*2 = 2$. So $P(A)=1/2$.

(b) B represents the (closed) unit circle. It's area is $\pi$. So $P(B)=\pi/4$.

(c) $C$ represents the closed line segment from $(0,1)$ to $(0,-1)$ (closed segment on the $y$-axis), but it will be more convenient to work with its complement. In particular, $C^c$ represents the entire square with the $y$-axis removed. However, you can write as the disjoint union $C^c = \left((0,1]\times [-1,1]\right)\cup \left([-1,0)\times [-1,1])\right)$. By properties of probability measures, the probability of $C^c$ is the sum of the probabilities of $C_1=(0,1]\times [-1,1]$ and $C_2=[-1,0)\times [-1,1]$. The areas of both $C_1$ and $C_2$ are equal to $2$, so the area of $C^c$ is $4$. So $P(C^c)=1$. Since $P(C)+P(C^c)=1$, we must have $P(C)=0$.

(d) $D$ represents the lower half of the unit circle cut off by the (dashed) line segment through $(-\sqrt{2}/2,-\sqrt{2}/2)$ and $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$. It's area is just $\pi/2$. So $P(D)=\pi/8$.

Comment: Shouldn't the area of C be zero? I see it as a line

Comment: Sorry, just made the corrections.

Comment: But shouldn't it be 1/2* pi * 1/4 in b)?

Comment: @user10930711 (b) is just the unit circle; it's area is $\pi$.

Comment: @user10930711 See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E2%2By%5E2+%3C%3D+1